# How can I combine PrettyPrintingJsonGeneratorDecorator and MaskingJsonGeneratorDecorator together?

Tags: java, logstash, logback, logstash-logback-encoder

I've tried to config the `logstash-logback-encoder` version `6.4` to print the pretty print JSON as

```xml
<appender name="consoleAsJSON" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LogstashEncoder">
        <includeCallerData>true</includeCallerData>
        <jsonGeneratorDecorator class="net.logstash.logback.decorate.PrettyPrintingJsonGeneratorDecorator"/>
    </encoder>
</appender>
```

The output is `pretty print` as expected. Then I step forward to config with masking as

```xml
<appender name="consoleAsJSON" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LogstashEncoder">
        <includeCallerData>true</includeCallerData>
        <jsonGeneratorDecorator class="net.logstash.logback.mask.MaskingJsonGeneratorDecorator">
            <defaultMask>XXXX</defaultMask>
            <path>password</path>
        </jsonGeneratorDecorator>
    </encoder>
</appender>
```

The output is `marked` as expected, too.

Anyhow when I combine these two together, it only does one thing, either `pretty print` or `masked`.

```xml
<appender name="consoleAsJSON" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LogstashEncoder">
        <includeCallerData>true</includeCallerData>
        <jsonGeneratorDecorator class="net.logstash.logback.decorate.PrettyPrintingJsonGeneratorDecorator"/>
        <jsonGeneratorDecorator class="net.logstash.logback.mask.MaskingJsonGeneratorDecorator">
            <defaultMask>XXXX</defaultMask>
            <path>password</path>
        </jsonGeneratorDecorator>
    </encoder>
</appender>
```

It only does the `masked`, but `not pretty print`.

```xml
<appender name="consoleAsJSON" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LogstashEncoder">
        <includeCallerData>true</includeCallerData>
        <jsonGeneratorDecorator class="net.logstash.logback.mask.MaskingJsonGeneratorDecorator">
            <defaultMask>XXXX</defaultMask>
            <path>password</path>
        </jsonGeneratorDecorator>
        <jsonGeneratorDecorator class="net.logstash.logback.decorate.PrettyPrintingJsonGeneratorDecorator"/>
    </encoder>
</appender>
```

It only does the `pretty print`, but `not masked`.

How can I combine `PrettyPrintingJsonGeneratorDecorator` and `MaskingJsonGeneratorDecorator` together? Could you please help to advise?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a [CompositeJsonGeneratorDecorator](https://github.com/logstash/logstash-logback-encoder/blob/logstash-logback-encoder-6.4/src/main/java/net/logstash/logback/decorate/CompositeJsonGeneratorDecorator.java), like this:

```xml
<appender name="consoleAsJSON" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LogstashEncoder">
        <includeCallerData>true</includeCallerData>
        <jsonGeneratorDecorator class="net.logstash.logback.decorate.CompositeJsonGeneratorDecorator">
            <decorator class="net.logstash.logback.decorate.PrettyPrintingJsonGeneratorDecorator"/>
            <decorator class="net.logstash.logback.mask.MaskingJsonGeneratorDecorator">
                <defaultMask>XXXX</defaultMask>
                <path>password</path>
            </decorator>
        </jsonGeneratorDecorator>
    </encoder>
</appender>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It works like a charm. Anyhow it would be nice if the documentation contains this example, as well.